# Want to Get Recommendation with Only "item ID" or With Out "user ID"

Tags: recommendation-engine, azure-cognitive-services

I am Getting good results with the procedure given [Microsoft Cognitive Api references](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f30d77eda5650db055a3db)but I want to find the recommendation with only "Item ID" i.e I don't want to use "User ID" as a input in usage file. my sample data contains only item specification.
My questions are

1. Can I upload the file with an alternative of " USER  ID" or Without user ID or Keeping it constant.
2. Can i get the item to item recommendation results For the same.

I tried to  keep "User ID" Constant for all but results are not appropriate it shows same recommendation for all Item and also tried removing "User ID" but usage not uploads with it.

Please Suggest me any possible way if exist to use the recommendation Api with out user ID.

Comment: It might help if you describe about what you have tried, or if you provided some code you wrote that did not do what you need to do.

Comment: I am calling api as give at[link](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f30d77eda5650db055a3d4)

And have made a data following 
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f316efeda5650db055a3e1

and
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f316efeda5650db055a3e2

But instead of using data in

Comment: Continue..
but instead of data format at
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f316efeda5650db055a3e2

or
<User Id>,<Item Id>,<Time>,[<Event type>]
I want want to use it with out item id as my data only contains item details and i want to get item recommendation only with item details